# How to make User Picture a required field?

Tags: 7, media

I do not see any option to make User Picture required in Account - Manage Field settings as it is not a real field in D7. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using these modules :

[Register with Picture](https://www.drupal.org/project/reg_with_pic)

> 1. Install and enable the module
> 2. Navigate to: **Configuration -> Account Settings**. (admin/config/people/accounts)
> 3. Check **Enable user pictures** if it isn't checked already.
> 4. Confirm **Enable pictures on registration** is checked.
> 5. Use the **Registration Picture Field Weight** field to adjust the display order of the picture field on the registration form. It can be
>      a negative or positive number.

[user picture field](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_picture_field)

> 1, Add a image field to user, for example "field_user_avatar"
>
> 2,config this field,and make it show on user register form.
>
> 3,install this module, navigate to
>   "admin/config/people/user_picture_field", here you can config the
>   "Machine name of source field that used as user picture"
>
> When user register an account, he/she upload an image through image
>   field "field_user_avatar", this image will be used as user's
>   picture(avatar).